# Using case switch with JSON data in Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have an issue with a project I'm working on. I'm using JSON to call data from OpenWeather's API, and using Javascript to use that data in conjunction with [Skycons](https://darkskyapp.github.io/skycons/) to output the current weather condition in the form of a Skycon. I'm using a case switch to take the [weather icon](https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions) called from OpenWeather and assign it to the corresponding Skycon.

My problem is the Skycon does not show.

My code:

```js
function startSkycons () {

    var weatherData = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Endicott,us&appid=5068bdb59997b9b9f98d00aedf1cc12f";

    $.getJSON(weatherData,function(data){

    var weatherIcon = (data.weather.icon);
    var icons = new Skycons({"color": "white"});
      icons.set("weatherIcon",Skycons.CLEAR_DAY);
      icons.set("weatherIcon", Skycons.CLEAR_NIGHT);
      icons.set("weatherIcon", Skycons.PARTLY_CLOUDY_DAY);
      icons.set("weatherIcon", Skycons.PARTLY_CLOUDY_NIGHT);
      icons.set("weatherIcon", Skycons.CLOUDY);
      icons.set("weatherIcon", Skycons.RAIN);
      icons.set("weatherIcon", Skycons.SLEET);
      icons.set("weatherIcon", Skycons.SNOW);
      icons.set("weatherIcon", Skycons.WIND);
      icons.set("weatherIcon", Skycons.FOG);

    switch (weatherIcon) {
        case "01d":
          skycons.add(document.getElementById("weatherIcon"), Skycons.CLEAR_DAY);
          break;
        case "01n":
          skycons.add(document.getElementById("weatherIcon"), Skycons.CLEAR_NIGHT);
          break;
        case "02d":
          skycons.add(document.getElementById("weatherIcon"), Skycons.PARTLY_CLOUDY_DAY);
          break;
        case "02n":
          skycons.add(document.getElementById("weatherIcon"), Skycons.PARTLY_CLOUDY_NIGHT);
          break;
        case: "03d":
          skycons.add(document.getElementById("weatherIcon"), Skycons.CLOUDY);
          break;
        case: "09d":
          skycons.add(document.getElementById("weatherIcon"), Skycons.RAIN);
          break;
        case: "13d":
          skycons.add(document.getElementById("weatherIcon"), Skycons.SNOW);
          break;
        case: "50d":
          skycons.add(document.getElementById("weatherIcon"), Skycons.FOG);
          break;

        default:

    }


      skycons.play();

}

startSkycons();
```

```css
body {
        background-color: #000; 
}

#time {
        top: 3%;
        left: 3%;
        position: fixed;
}

#timeModule {
        font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 64px;
}

#date {
        font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 18px;
        top: 15%;
        left: 4%;
        position: fixed;
}

#weather {
      top: 5%;
      left: 70%;
      position: fixed;
      width: 30%;
      height: 250px;
}

#weatherIcon {
      left: 0%;
      position: absolute;
}

.weatherTemp {
      font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
      color: #FFF;
      font-size: 64px;
}


#weatherTemp {
      display: table;
      margin: 0 auto;
}

.weatherTown {
      font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
      color: #FFF;
      font-size: 30px;
}

#weatherTown {
      display: table;
      margin: 0 auto;
      top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
      <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css">

      <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:200" rel="stylesheet">

      <!-- JS -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/skycons.js"></script>
        <script src="js/skycons2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/time.js"></script>
        <script src="js/date.js"></script>
        <script src="js/weather.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="time">
      <div id="timeModule"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="date">
      <div id="dateModule"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="weather">
        <canvas id="weatherIcon"></canvas>

        <span id="weatherTemp" class="weatherTemp"></span>
        <span id="weatherTown" class="weatherTown"></span>
    </div>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `"message": "SyntaxError: expected expression, got ':'",` - this is the message in the **developer** tools console (and in the output of the snippet) - when debugging code in a browser, get used to checking this developer tools console for errors that are simple to fix

Comment: i.e. `case: "03d", "03n", "04d", "04n":` is not valid syntax - please read some [documentation for switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) the first example shows how to deal with your requirements (i.e. Mangoes and Papayas)

Comment: so, instead of `case: "50d", "50n":` it's `case "50d": case "50n":`

Comment: I edited the switch cases to exclude the improper syntax but the issue persists

Comment: what issue? has to be a different issue now -

Comment: the skycon still doesn't show

Comment: oh, wait you haven't fixed the syntax issue at all `case: "09d":` . should be `case "09d":` - also you've removed a lot of "cases" rather than use the **correct** syntax

Comment: you're also missing `});
}` at the end of your function, and `skycons` and `Skycons` are `undefined` - so ... lots of issues in your code still

Comment: please at least *try* to use your browsers **developer** tools console to debug basic typos/syntax errors/missing variables etc - the browser is telling you what you're doing wrong

Comment: you're right, I'm sorry. I actually was using the developers tools, but only the Elements tab, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Hari Setiawan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8252588/hari-setiawan) and Jaromanda X's help, I've solved the issue.

For anyone who might run into a similar issue, my problem was: the syntax of the switch, as pointed out by both aforementioned people, and the fact that I did not define `skycons`. I switch `icons` to `skycons` in the JS file and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code here

```
case: "03d":
      skycons.add(document.getElementById("weatherIcon"), Skycons.CLOUDY);
      break;
    case: "09d":
      skycons.add(document.getElementById("weatherIcon"), Skycons.RAIN);
      break;
    case: "13d":
      skycons.add(document.getElementById("weatherIcon"), Skycons.SNOW);
      break;
    case: "50d":
      skycons.add(document.getElementById("weatherIcon"), Skycons.FOG);
      break;
```

you've add extra colon there after the "case" syntax, instead you should write like this

```
    case "03d":
      skycons.add(document.getElementById("weatherIcon"), Skycons.CLOUDY);
      break;
    case "09d":
      skycons.add(document.getElementById("weatherIcon"), Skycons.RAIN);
      break;
    case "13d":
      skycons.add(document.getElementById("weatherIcon"), Skycons.SNOW);
      break;
    case "50d":
      skycons.add(document.getElementById("weatherIcon"), Skycons.FOG);
      break;
```

Try it, feel free to ask more

Comment: Unfortunately the issue persists, the icon still does not show.

Comment: @Jay - because `skycons` and `Skycons` are undefined, there's missing closing braces ... all of these things are spelled out in the **developer tools console** which you seem to be ignoring - your browser is telling you what you've done wrong!